# Cannot authenticate to nuget feed in Visual Studio Team Services (was VSO) with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, azure-devops

We have a nuget feed set up on our Team Services account. With VS 2015, I can authenticate no problem, using the Microsoft login form.

With Visual Studio 2013, it pops up very generic authentication form, which keeps popping up no matter what I input to it. Has anyone else come across this? Any way around it?

[image]

Normally, I would just use 2015 to authenticate then 2013 would be fine. Unfortunately, I can't get 2015 to run on my pc anymore - so I need to make this work with 2013.

Comment: If the VS2015 works well, just the VS2013 has this issue, you would check the detailed requirements for authenticating to feeds with NuGet: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/auth

Comment: So am I understanding that page correctly - there really isn't support for 2013? I'd have to use Nuget.exe? The auth helper sounds promising. Thank you for the link - I'll try a few of these options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticate to VSTS feed via "Nuget Package Manager" requires VS2015 Update1 and later just as the information mentioned in the page provided by Jack.

If you don't mind to store the credential in "Nuget.config" file, you could use [Personal Access Token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/auth#personal-access-tokens) method which support all nuget client and easy to use. And Nuget Auth Helper is also a good method to do this.